# Using gRPC without manually converting models between DTO and Proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

My project uses a microservice architecture with transport in the form of gRPC.

Initially, I described the message that was generated in the go structure in .proto and I used it.

But then I encountered the problem of the lack of configurability of some fields of this structure (for example, it is very problematic to work with time or custom data types), so it was decided to use an internal DTO, but the problem arose of converting the internal model into a proto and back with each request.

Now, to write one handler, I need to make 4 conversion models between structures, which takes a lot of time and creates place for bugs, and also because of this it is difficult to keep the fields up to date if they are added

I also tried to make a crutch in the form of conversion via json or another tag, but then I encounter the inappropriateness of using gRPC, because automatic conversion slows down the application and also it does not eliminate bugs if the fields have different tags

I'm looking for a solution where using proto doesn't increase development time that much

I know about the gogoproto tool, but it is already deprecated and I did not find clear instructions on the Internet on how to work with it

Comment: It's not clear how `gogo` would have solved the problem here, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem. The replacement for `gogo` is `vtproto`, which works very well — it's just scoped for fast unmarshaling/marshaling and not conversion.

Comment: That being said, have you looked at the "well-known types" protobuf packages? They extend the base types and make using protos for your main application types feasible. For example, it has proper timestamp, with helpers to convert between `time.Time` and `timestamppb.Time`: https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/ and https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/dos-donts/#well-known-common